# Shape not identified in visio using c#

Tags: c#, add-in, visio, connector

Hi  am trying to read the content of a visio page where as am able to read the below images and it shapes along with the connectors too ,where as am able to read this type of connectors,

[image]

but am not able to identify the connectors of the below image but an able to nread the content of the image.
[image]

the below method is to find wether its connectors or not

```
    private bool IsConnector(Shape shape)
    {
        string objType = shape.get_Cells("objType").Formula;
        if (objType == "2")
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

where as if the connector is in the shape similar to first image then am getting value **2 in objTyp** ,but it return value **0 for second image**.

1. I need to know what is the purpose of using `string objType = shape.get_Cells("objType").Formula;` ,because it return 2 for connectors in firstImage and other value for connector in second image
2. Why it return other that 2 for the connectors in second image.

Answer (score 0):

You could be using the `Shape.OneD` property because all connectors are OneD == 1 (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff768968.aspx )
The ObjType cell (https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff765987.aspx) specifies if a an shape is placeable or routable.
In the second image it is quite possible that the connectors are merely connecting the images together, and are not actually routable.